# How to select a node with XPath that can be on different levels in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

i'm trying to parse an xml like this in c# with xpath

```
<Validation>
    <Presentation>
        <Slide Name = "Slide3">
            <Shape Name = "Title">
                <FontSize Value = "36"/>
            </Shape>
        </Slide>
        <Shape Name = "Title">
            <FontSize Value = "36"/>
        </Shape>
    </Presentation>
</Validation>
```

so, the "Shape" tag can be under the "Slide" tag and also under the "Presentation" Tag. Is there a way to take both nodes with xpath?

Answer (score 2):

All Shapes with ancestors Slide and Presentation

```
//Shape[ancestor::Slide and ancestor::Presentation]
```

For your xml finds only

```
Element='<Shape Name="Title">
  <FontSize Value="36" />
</Shape>'
```

If you want be sure that Presentation is upper than Slide:

```
//Shape[ancestor::Slide[ancestor::Presentation]]
```

Comment: can i also filter for "shape" attribute?

Comment: @Matt3o   //Shape[ancestor::Slide[ancestor::Presentation] and @Name="Title"]

Comment: @Matt3o On the site It is taken as a rule to accept the correct answers marking them. I see, you don't. You are not right

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like (assuming `doc` is `XElement` you've loaded xml into)

```
doc.XPathSelectElements("//Shape");
```

Here XPath expression `//Shape` selects all `<Shape>` nodes in the document from the `doc` node no matter where they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to xml and do something like

```
var xmlparsed = XElement.Parse(xml);
var shapes = xmlparsed.Elements().Descendants("Shape");
```

Comment: Well, technically OP wanted to do it using XPath expression.

Comment: LOL I know. Just putting an alternate solution out there using Linq to xml. But you are right he asked about XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Xpath

```
//Shape
```

this will give you both the shape node

```
<Shape Name="Title">
  <FontSize Value="36" />
</Shape>
<Shape Name="Title">
  <FontSize Value="36" />
</Shape>
```